# Component recommendation for my PCB (probe)

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, connector, kicad, probe

I have completed hardware and software (on the Arduino platform) for measuring resistance on custom sensors.

Now it is time to move away from the breadboard and use my own PCB (I plan to make it on top of the Arduino, in the form of a shield.)

The problem is I don't know what components to use as the probe to perform the measurement.

Take a look the the sensor:

[image]

As you can see, the probes are soldered on the sensor.

The other end of the probe cable looks something like this:

[image]

[image]

I need some components that will go out of the board and I can solder to the sensor.
But, since I want to address 8 sensors, this means 16 cables, so the size has to be as small as possible - not like those huge oscilloscope-like connectors in the picture.

Ideally, I want them to be as basic as possible - since I plan to use Fritzing. I want to stay away from Kicad, as I want to prototype it as soon as possible.

Is there any standard and basic solution to use as a probe?

Comment: There are probably several thousand suitable connectors. You could consider some type of audio jack. They're cheap although contact resistance may be problematic for your application.

Comment: I don't really care about contact resistance. I am doing this as a proof of concept for my university. Still, i don't know where to find any. Could you name some common (and small to fit) connectors, that their footprint is ease to find on pcb creation software?

Comment: @user1584421:  I would advise you to use KiCAD rather than Fritzing.  The disadvantages of working around the short comings of a half-assed program (Fritzing) will out weigh the learning curve you might encounter in using KiCAD.

Comment: Those "huge oscilloscope type connectors" are banana plugs, and are rarely used with oscilloscopes.

Comment: What is the nature of the sensor?  Exactly what sort of signals are present in the wires?

Comment: It is a resistance sensor. Nothing too fancy. Standard electrical signal that the arduino can read.

Comment: The problem in my situation, is i need to find both a footprint to use on my pcb AND a real life component to insert and solder to the sensor.

Comment: 1.  Find the proper connector.  2.  Draw the footprint in your design software.  3.  Don't try it with Fritzing.  Fritzing makes it darn near impossible to draw your own footprints.  KiCAD and other programs expect you to make your own footprints, so it is much easier than drawing footprints for Fritzing.

Comment: I should also note that in my breadboard application i use standard wires that go inside the breadboard, and solder them to the sensor on the other end. Of course i could try this as well, bit it seems unprofessional.

Comment: You can't meaningfully select something until you are more specific about the requirement.  Look at what equipment of similar purposes uses, and contemplate why.

Comment: You  do not 'need', nor do you want, it to be "as small as possible". You really want a 1.25mm pitch board-to-wire connector? They're available. Probably the ones that hobbyists call "JST" would work for you (JST is a large ($100bn) Japanese company with a great many connector products).

Comment: You can use IDC connector and split other end of flat cable to individual wires. It is not easy to solder them, though - wire is too thin and easy to break when you remove insulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally went ahead with simple pin headers.